# How would I use arrays in Bash to symlink ALL dotfiles to their correct directories (Including files in nested Dotfiles directories)?

Tags: bash, scripting, symlink, dotfiles

So, I am trying to use Bash to automate dotfiles. **Before you ask, this is not the problem. I have that part figured out.** Here is what my code looks like:

```
configs=(
    ~/.config/alacritty
    ~/.config/dunst
    ~/.config/flameshot
    ~/.config/i3
    ~/.config/i3status
    ~/.config/kitty
    ~/.config/nvim
    ~/.config/picom
    ~/.config/rofi
    ~/.config/gtk-3.0
    ~/.config/obs-studio
    ~/.config/sway
    ~/.config/waybar
    ~/.config/swappy
    ~/.config/mako
    ~/.config/swaylock
    ~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/User/settings.json
)

for name in "${configs[@]}"; do
    if [ ! -e "$name" ]; then
        echo "$name does not exist."
        ln -sfv "$HOME/Dotfiles/configs/${name##*/}" "$name"
    else
        echo "$name exists."
    fi
done
```

Well, there's an issue there. It works perfectly fine until it gets to attempting to symlink `~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/User/settings.json`. When symlinking, the Bash script ignores everything up until the last `/`.

This means that when I run the script, it creates a file in `~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/User/settings.json` that directs itself to `~/Dotfiles/configs/settings.json`, and not the `Code\ -\ OSS` directory that I created in `Dotfiles`.

How do I set this up so that it will symlink all of those files in the array above so that it redirects to the corresponding `Dotfiles` file?

Comment: An alternative would be to use [stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/stow.html). This pattern is exactly what it's for, but it's not necessarily as fun as rolling your own! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Focusing on the last element in the array, you are executing:

```
ln -sfv "$HOME/Dotfiles/configs/settings.json" ~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/User/settings.json
```

(assuming the subdirectories already exist)

Then the following symlink is created:

```
~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/User/settings.json -> ~/Dotfiles/configs/settings.json
```

(Please note the *lhs* is the symlink name and the *rhs* is the actual file.)

Your mentioned results are very natural behavior.
Instead, if you want to create the symlink such as:

```
~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/User/settings.json -> ~/Dotfiles/configs/Code\ -\ OSS/User/settings.json
```

Then you will need to say:

```
for name in "${configs[@]}"; do
    if [ ! -e "$name" ]; then
        echo "$name does not exist."
        ln -sfv "$HOME/Dotfiles/configs/${name#*config/}" "$name"
    else
        echo "$name exists."
    fi
done
```